# ¿Por qué no puedo ver el diseño de una vista creada en XAML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm

Estoy revisando una demo que he descargado de la página CodeProject que me permite ver cómo se realiza el acceso a base de datos utilizando MVVM y XAML. El programa compila y funciona, llega a abrir el formulario, pero tengo errores en el diseño.

La demo la descargué de este link:
[Demo CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124160/Using-WPF-MVVM-for-Database-Access)

El proyecto es antiguo y por eso me pide migrar, estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2012 Update 5.

El mensaje de error en la parte de diseño es el siguiente:

> Invalid Markup - Check the Error List for more information.

Y en la parte de los mensajes de error del proyecto al compilar me dice lo siguiente:

> The name "ProductDisplayModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ProductMvvm.ViewModels".

He compilado varias veces, he borrado temporales, he limpiado el proyecto y lo he vuelto a generar, lo he eliminado y vuelto a descomprimir, pero no he logrado ver el diseño del `View`.

¿Alguna idea de por qué no me muestra el diseño de la vista/formulario?

Comment: El proyecto original en que versión fue desarrollado

Comment: No lo menciona en la página de CodeProject pero por la fecha de publicación parece que fue hecho para VS 2010, podría estar equivocado.

Comment: Puedes abrir el archivo de solución con un editor de textos y casi al principio del archivo debe venir la versión de visual studio.

Comment: Para 2010 deberia decir algo como `Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual C# Express 2010`

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008

Comment: y aclaremos q en vs 2015 luego de compilar anduvo todo

Comment: Hay un programa que se llama Gorilla Player, para poder visualizar los archivos axml. Es una extensión de Visual Studio